# Is there a better way to find the ID of something in a table, even if it doesn't exist [mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql

I very frequently use logic something like this when writing to normalised databases.

In pseudocode:

```
is the thing I want in the table?:
    yes - get it's ID
else
    no - insert it, then get it's ID
```

In PHP:

```
// is the useragent in the useragent table?
// if so, find the id, else, insert and find.
$useragentResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM useragent WHERE name = '".$useragent."' LIMIT 1");
if ($useragentResult->num_rows == 0) {
    // It is not in there
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO useragent (name) VALUES ('".$useragent."')");

    $resultID_object = $mysqli->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id");
    $row = $resultID_object->fetch_object();
    $useragentID = $row->id;
} else {
    // It is, so find it and set it
    $useragentData = $useragentResult->fetch_object();
    $useragentID = $useragentData->id;
}
```

This feels ugly (not just due to PHP!), and common enough that perhaps there is a better way.

What's the real way of doing this, or is this the best way?

Comment: Rich, with a 17.2k rep I *really* hope you know lil' [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Don't worry - this code was written just for this question - in the real code things are carefully checked.

Comment: I thought as much - just thought it wise to have the warning there for any other readers of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Since [MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` inserts or updates a row, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

Or in [earlier versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` inserts a row, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. If the statement updates a row instead, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not meaningful. However, you can work around this by using `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`. Suppose that `id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. To make `LAST_INSERT_ID()` meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
> ```

Comment: This seems close, but it doesn't seem to select the id of the existing row, which is what I need.

Comment: It should do... I presume there is a `UNIQUE KEY` defined on your  `name` column, so that the `INSERT` fails and resorts to `UPDATE` instead?  Have you tried `... UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`?

Comment: The table I have has just id and hash. id is the auto incrementing primary key, hash is unique. I'm trying 'INSERT INTO user (hash) VALUES ('847222f4012292581db626ced4e84c8f') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)', Where that hash exists with id 1. I get back that 0 rows have been inserted, and that inserted id = 0. Weird?

Comment: Very.  It's working for me... perhaps you can `SHOW CREATE TABLE user` in your question?  Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL is 5.0. I can get it if I run SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() afterwards - maybe that's what I should have been doing all along?

Comment: Ha.  Yes, sorry.  I had assumed you were.

Comment: Thanks for your help looks like this is working now - knew that I was doing things wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It is ugly only insofar as you are using some basic PHP without taking full advantage of the language. For operations like this Object Oriented Programming comes in very handy. Rewriting your database access into classes would yield code more like this:

```
$userAgent = new UserAgent();
$userAgent->name = $useragent;
$results = $userAgent->find();
if (empty($results)) {
    $userAgent->save();
}
$userAgentId = $userAgent->id;
```

In that example the find method of your UserAgent class does all the SQL work behind the scenes. If the find returns empty we call the save method which does an insert based on the properties that are populated and automatically populates the id property. So now after the if statement I know the id is populated either by a successful find() or by the save().